# NET8 Blazor failed integrity metadata check

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

Here we go again. I have created a new `Blazor` application with `NET8`. I started from scratch a new project using the template in the new version of Visual Studio 2022.

I deployed the project on my server hosted by an internet provider. The project has a "server" project and a client project. Also, I have some Blazor components: from them, I read the CSS and JS (here are just 2 errors but the list is quite long and similar). The components are added as dependencies in both projects (server and client).

When I open the website, the result is different from the operating system. For example, on Safari on Mac I can see the page as I expected but I get a lot of errors:

> [Error] Failed integrity metadata check. https://languageinuse.com/_framework/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.wasm. Failed integrity metadata check. Content length: 1233, Expected content length: 1233, Expected metadata: sha256-9I89fTt452+42ZDGVwyx5nG+GrUFUO1ocB1K9iqncwE=
>
> [Error] Failed integrity metadata check. https://languageinuse.com/_framework/System.Xml.Linq.wasm. Failed integrity metadata check. Content length: 1233, Expected content length: 1233, Expected metadata: sha256-GWFwZbLHxhganNs3G9GJMiuMxZ+GJwv4j+F7g493lik=

[image]

[image]

When I use Microsoft Edge on Mac and Windows, the website has a lot more errors but in this case, it is a mix of integrity errors and missing resources. The missing resources are the resources embedded in the Blazor components.

[image]

[image]

Using Chrome on Windows and Mac, the result is the same as Edge.

[image]

Is there a way to fix those issues?

Comment: How about compare the file size from running on visual studio and deployment.

Comment: File size of what? In my local machine, I don't have any errors.

Comment: I mean the working file size and error file size. I used to have integrity check failure because internet provider compress html/js files.

Comment: You "deployed" it how?

Comment: Yes, on the website.